# HTTP request not working in nextron (nextjs+electron) in production build

Tags: next.js, axios, electron, electron-builder, next-auth

I don't know what I am missing and I tried to find the solution all over the internet but can't seem to find anything remotely related to my issue.

I have create an electron app using 'nextron' on my already made nextjs app, everything seems to be working perfectly on `development` but just as i created a production build, every network call (API Calls) are now with the protocol of '`app://`' instead of '`https://`'.
And that is a very major issue for me as I am using this app for API calls, authentication (next-auth) and obviously when calling with 'app://' protocol.
I am using axios for my own API calls and the call in the snapshot is being made by 'next-auth' for authentication behind the scenes.

P.S. The above is only happening when on production build, everything is working fine on development. I am using this as a boiler plate: https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron/tree/main/examples/with-material-ui

[image: my electron app, trying to authenticate using 'provider' api from next-auth]

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and from what I found out API calls only work in development mode. Sorry that I can't be much of a help. This is the github issue I came across.

[github issue here](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron/issues/43#issuecomment-1418652348)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need the to set the NEXTAUTH_URL in your environment to direct your nextauth calls to a specific URL scheme like app:// I think NEXTAUTH, also has a baseUrl option, but I am not sure how that works, so I can't give you pointers on how to use it.